# 501(c)(3) Bylaws Question - Does this clause mean a motion to amend bylaws can go forward without quorum?

Tags: non-profit, parliamentary-procedure

**Voting Rights**

> e. Quorum at annual or special meetings will be at least 51 percent of the directors and the lesser of 10 percent of the voting members or 10 voting members including any proxies.
>
> f.    Voting on matters unrelated to the board elections will proceed
>   with a motion, discussion and passed by a majority of members in
>   attendance so long as those present represent a quorum.

**Amendments**

> The Membership may amend these bylaws by a two-thirds (2/3)
>   vote of the membership voting at the annual or special meeting

Answer (score 3):

**No**

An amendment must happen at a meeting: without a quorum there is no meeting.

Comment: The meeting is required to take place by the bylaws. Sorry I should have mentioned that. So quorum is not required for the meeting to take place, but presumably is for the motion to be voted on. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I misunderstood what quorum meant. I believed that 51% of board's agreement was needed, not just their presence.

Comment: In the absence of a quorum a meeting **cannot** be held - that's what the word means